# Mock Windows 10 build version

Tags: windows, windows-10

I recently installed Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro mid-2014 using BootCamp Assistant. The only windows version I could use was the 1507 version, the original release in july 2015. I can't use more recent versions due to drivers issues.

Unfortunately, one of my program refuses to install on this old version of windows, it says that the operating system is "unsupported". After some diggings it needs at least the 1803 build of windows, which I can't install.

My intuition is that the installer just checks if windows build is greater or equals to 1803 before proceeding. I can't help but wonder if this check really serve a purpose. Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to **mock my windows build**, by  manually changing the displayed version from 1507 to 1803 for instance (by editing a key somewhere)?
If this is possible, what could happen to my computer if I try to change it?

It is just to bypass the installation check, afterwards I would reset it back to 1507.

Answer (score 1):

Usually such restrictions are related to new API introduced in
later versions, so your installation method might or not work, but
the product itself might not function correctly.

To answer the question :
The version build number is found in the registry at key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`,
items `CurrentBuild` and `CurrentBuildNumber`.

For version 1507, both should be set to `10240`.
For version 1803, the value is `17134.1` (or perhaps only `17134`).
More build numbers can be found at Wikipedia
[Windows 10 version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history).

Changing these items might be sufficient for tricking this one
installation.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try this out and see if it works out! 
As said in a comment below, what makes me believe that this might work is that it actually works on Windows 7 (which I can't install either btw), yet it is written that it shouldn't on the website. To me, it looks like a random check, maybe the current version at the time of the development.

Comment: Tried but no luck the check must be targeting something else...
Thank you for your help !

Comment: If it works on Windows 7, you could set the installation process to compatibility with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to mock my windows
> build,

Not at all likely and if some limited success, updates will break it.

Use a Virtual Machine instead.  VMware Fusion works.

Install Fusion and then you can easily use a modern version of Windows 10.

Comment: That was an option I considered too, but I am not sure that my mac will be able to handle windows 10 running in a virtual machine...

Comment: It is worth a try (use Fusion Trial Version).  2014 is not so old that it should not work.

Comment: I'll try this out and post the results! thank for re-opening this option